# Link with anchor navigation in Grails

Tags: grails

How to make link like `/news/index#partition` with `Grails` tag `g:link`

Current is `<g:link controller="news" action="index">News</g:link>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you can do

```
<a href="${createLink(controller: "news", action:"index") + "#partition"}">News</a>
```